# Extract json spreadsheet data using Powershell and then copying to a different column

Tags: json, excel, powershell

I have a spreadsheet that lists data in multiple columns. I am using `Excel.Application` using COM interface to read the spreadsheet.

One of the columns (named Tags) has JSON (key/value pairs) entries in it, for example:

row 1: `{"Environment":"Test","displayName":"TestServer"}`

row 2: `{"Environment":"Dev","displayName":"TestServer2"}`

I would like to put these values into their own key columns, so there would be a column called 'Environment' with 'Test' in row 1 and Dev in row 2 and a column called 'DisplayName' with 'TestServer' in row 1 and Testserver2 in row 2 and so on with all the other rows.

Is it possible to loop through all the rows and to have the value put into its 'key' column using PowerShell?

This is my existing code:

```
$file = “c:\sandpit\testdata.xlsx”
$sheetName = "Sheet1"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false

$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$rowOwner,$colOwner = 1,1
$rowName,$colName = 1,2
$rowTags,$colTags = 1,3

for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
    {
$owner = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowOwner+$i,$colOwner).text
$name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i,$colName).text
$tags = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowTags+$i,$colTags).text | ConvertFrom-Json |    Select DisplayName,CreatedBy

Write-Host $owner, $name, $tags

}

$objExcel.quit()
get-process excel | stop-process
```

Comment: Take your row and column index and use convertfrom-json. That will return a powershell object and use column offsets or similar to populate the desired data? Would be nice to see your code and any attempts you may have tried.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I have added the code. I can convert the json but am not understanding how you would use the key to create a column with the value in the corresponding cell? Any ideas?? Thanks.

Comment: Need sample data for better accuracy.

Comment: Okay, so for example, column one and two are labelled Owner and Name and the third column is labelled tags with the following data:
{"Environment":"Test","displayName":"TestServer"} . So a new column called Environement with Test as the value and displayName with Testserver as the value is what is reqiured. Hope this makes sense.